# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Credit'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, visual-studio-2013

I am really struggling with Html.DropdownList. Identical code worked under VS2012 but fails with the subject error under VS2013. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Controller (selectedCredit is int):

```
var creditQuery = from d in db.CreditStatus
                    orderby d.CreditId
                    select new { d.CreditId, d.Reason };
ViewBag.Credit = new SelectList(creditQuery.ToList(), "CreditId", "Reason", selectedCredit);
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Credit", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If the second parm of Html.DropdownList is not null, it will ignore selectedCredit and no item will be selected.

List list shows correctly but fails on Post with the subject error. HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you do a POST to server the viewbag needs to be repopulated

Insert this in your post action

```
var creditQuery = from d in db.CreditStatus
                orderby d.CreditId
                select new { d.CreditId, d.Reason };
ViewBag.Credit = new SelectList(creditQuery.ToList(), "CreditId", "Reason", selectedCredit);
```

Comment: Thank you, scartag and Morten! You are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If your POST controller doesn't do a redirect GET, you have to repopulate the ViewBag again cause you are showing the same View.

So in your Post controller put the same values inside the `ViewBag.Credit`